# For loop only executing once?

Tags: c++

I don't know if I'm just being stupid, but Visual Studio says that my for loop is only executing once, and it does seem to be the case. However I can't figure out why. I'd really appreciate it if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
for (int i = (nbToVerify - 1); i == 1; i--)
    {
        if (nbToVerify % i == 0)
        {
            nbIsPrime = false;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            nbIsPrime = true;
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `nbToVerify`?

Comment: Please make this a [mcve]. What is `nbToVerify`?

Comment: Ya'll got tricked by an external symbol !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i == 1` should be `i != 1`, that's it.